# How to print out values and items in a dictionary, python

Tags: python

I have this code

```
    global listplanets
    listplanets = {
        "Mercury": 0.378,
        "Venus": 0.907,
        "Mars": 0.377,
        "Io": 0.1835,
        "Europa": 0.1335,
        "Ganymede": 0.1448,
        "Callisto": 0.1264,}

    lines = ['{}'.format(body) for body in listplanets]
    print('\n'.join(lines))
```

How do I print out everything in the dictionary? Each definition needs to align with the value in the output. I would greatly appreciate anyone's help! :)

Comment: You can simply print all elements using `print("\n".join( list( k + " : " + str(v) for k,v in listplanets.items() ) ))`

Comment: @aminrd Thank you so much! Can you put this in the answer section so I can tick it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use:

```py
print("\n".join( list( k + " : " + str(v) for k,v in listplanets.items() ) ))
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy (and readale) solution:

```py
for planet, v in listplanets:
    print(f"{planet}: {v}")
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, when I so this it will say there is too much to unpack but I have gotten my answer from someone else. Cheers again  :)